# Does Cloudant on Bluemix have a performance issue?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a mobile app using Cloudant CDTReplicator to synch the local datastore and the remote DB. The app was fast at the start, but then the synch would take more than 10 seconds when there are just 180 normal documents, each having a few string fields in the remote DB. And the delta between the local and remote is minimal. 
After I deleted all the 180 documents, it speeds up greatly. So looks like it is related to number of documents.
Can you please let me know if there is a performance issue with Cloudant replication? Or this is a problem with my coding? The code is just to start the replicator, not much there.

Thank you,

Jen

Comment: maybe including the code would help others answer your question

Comment: @ZhengXie Did you contact the support for this ?

Comment: Tell us about your mobile app please.  Also, is this a new issue or is this something that you've consistently seen?

Comment: I am facing this problem too, any updates about this?

Answer (score 0):

From the status page https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status Cloudant is reported as having some issues on US-South. The problem is related though to a "service broker timeout" generic message.

Comment: The status page says there is problem with new user sign on. This is not my issue though. and after deleting the 180 documents, I found the replication is much faster. So the service isn't down.